# Access an element of list within itself in R

Tags: r

I can make a list containing a function, e.g.,

```
foo <- list(value=1, func=function(x) x+1)
```

Then `foo$func(3)` gives `4`. But is it possible for the `$func` function to have access the `$value` element in the same list? I've tried the following, which is (obviously) wrong:

```
foo <- list(value=1, func=function(x) x+value)
foo$func(3)
# Error in foo$func(3) : object 'value' not found
```

I know the following codes work:

```
bar <- list(value=1, func=function(FOO,x) x+FOO$value)
bar$func(bar, 3)
# [1] 4
func <- function(FOO,x) x+FOO$value
func(foo,3)
# [1] 4
```

But I want to use the `foo$func(3)` syntax, rather than `func(foo,3)`, for some reasons. Can this be achieved by R?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Beside the helpful answers below, `?ReferenceClasses` is also useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with the `proto` package.

```
library("proto")

foo <- proto(value = 1, func = function(., x) x + .$value)

foo$func(3)
#> [1] 4

foo$value <- 7
foo$func(10)
#> [1] 17
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks. `proto` looks very interesting.

Answer (score 5):

```
foo <- list(value = 1, func = function(x) x + foo$value)
foo$func(3)
```

Is this good enough for you?

Comment: This is nice. But sometimes I want to do `bar <- foo; rm(foo)` and then call `bar$func(3)`. Anyway, thanks. I see that my wording was not really clear.